# Appending a column in .csv with Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Intro Python question: I am working on a program that counts the number of politicians in each political party for each session of the U.S. Congress. I'm starting from a .csv with biographical data, and wish to export my political party membership count as a new .csv. This is what I'm doing:

```
import pandas as pd

read = pd.read_csv('30.csv', delimiter = ';', names = ['Name', 'Years', 'Position', 'Party', 'State', 'Congress'])

party_count = read.groupby('Party').size()

with open('parties.csv', 'a') as f:
    party_count.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

This updates my .csv to read as follows:

```
'Year','Party','Count'
'American Party',1
'Democrat',162
'Independent Democrat',3
'Party',1
'Whig',145
```

I next need to include the date under my first column ('Year'). This is contained in the 'Congress' column in my first .csv. What do I need to add to my final line of code to make this work?

Here is a snippet from the original .csv file I am drawing from:

```
'Name';'Years';'Position';'Party';'State';'Congress'
'ABBOTT, Amos';'1786-1868';'Representative';'Whig';'MA';'1847'
'ADAMS, Green';'1812-1884';'Representative';'Whig';'KY';'1847'
'ADAMS, John Quincy';'1767-1848';'Representative';'Whig';'MA';'1847'
```

Comment: Can you point the cvs file somewhere?  or if you can show us starting few line od DataFrame.

Comment: Here's a snippet from the original csv file:
    'Name';'Years';'Position';'Party';'State';'Congress'
    'ABBOTT, Amos';'1786-1868';'Representative';'Whig';'MA';'1847'

Here's what the second csv file looks like (sans date):
    'Year','Party','Count'
    'American Party',1
    'Democrat',162
    'Independent Democrat',3
    'Whig',145

Comment: sorry could understand,  do you want to add a column `date` before `Year`, Is that what you asking?

Comment: Yes. Right now the column header is correct, but there's no data below the header.

Comment: Something here seems wrong. If your columns are ['Name', 'Years', 'Position', 'Party', 'State', 'Congress'] and you groupby "party". your columns should be ['Name', 'Years', 'Position', 'State', 'Congress']. Also why not just using: `party_count.to_csv("parties.csv", header=False)`, if header is false you area not supposed to see 'Year','Party','Count' in your csv.

Comment: Would you be able to share the CSV file, it looks to be present on kaggle?

Answer (score 2):

You can merge back the counts of Party to your original dataframe by:

```
party_count = df.groupby('Party').size().reset_index(name='Count')
df = df.merge(party_count, on='Party', how='left')
```

Once you have the count of parties now you can select your data. For eg: If you need [Congress, Party, Count] you can use:

```
out_df = df[['Congress ', 'Party', 'Count']].drop_duplicates()
out_df.columns = ['Year', 'Party', 'Count']
```

Here, out_df being the dataframe you can write to my.csv file.

```
out_df.to_csv('my.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: This almost did it. I just needed to add index=False when I wrote to the new .csv. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CharlieGoldberg consider accepting an answer by clicking the checkmark if your question is solved. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlieGoldberg Does this completes your question??